# Ruby yield called from within Integer#times not returning the evaluated block

Tags: ruby, yield, implicit

Got a very simple question why when I  define a block as so:

```
def test
yield
end

a=test{7} => a=7
```

yet when I define a block like this

```
def test(n)

n.times{ yield }
end
a=test(4){7} => 4
```

why does the return value become n not yield?

Answer (score 4):

It is returning the value from [`Integer#times`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) (which happens to be same number on which you called the method - as can be seen on [the Rubinius source](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/e065959680bfdd3801fb794f617ade9dfac5bf32/kernel/common/integer.rb#L193) or on [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/integer/times_spec.rb)) instead of the block return value.

Since [`Integer#times`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) calls the block multiple times, you have basically two alternatives to that:

1. Combine the results of all the calls on an array and return that.

   ```
   def test(n)
     result = []
     n.times { |current| result << yield(current) }
     result
   end

   # Or, leveranging Enumerator#map:

   def test(n)
     n.times.map { |current| yield(current) }
   end

   # Or, still shorter, by forwarding the block:

   def test(n, &block)
     n.times.map(&block)
   end

   test(4) { |n| n * 2 } # => [0, 2, 4, 6]
   ```
2. Store the last value returned from the block on a variable, and return it:

   ```
   def test(n)
     result = nil
     n.times { |current| result = yield(current) }
     result
   end

   test(4) { |n| n * 2 } # => 6
   ```

Comment: Times doesn't return the number of iterations.  You can give it a -15 for example and it will return -15, which happens to be NOT the number of iterations.  No, it actually returns `self`, which is the Integer that times was called on.

Comment: @vgoff true, thanks for the correction. Would you mind editing the answer?

Comment: Yes, actually.  Otherwise I would have simply done so.  There may be other things you would like to express in your answer as well, while updating the answer.  I would not know.  For instance, your second point may not be expressed very clearly, as you just stated that the return is not from the block, yet you then state that you can return the value returned from the last block.

Comment: @vgoff Thanks, I was able to improve it thanks to your comments. Anything else to add?

Comment: Other nuances, for sure, but I feel this covers the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source, [`times`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) method will return the number of times it ran, not the result of the block it runs.

Comment: If you look at the documentation it states "times {|i| block } → self"  (if given a block) so it returns self.  `Self` being the `num` in the source code.  And if you use -15 it will return that, but it isn't the number of times it ran.  All the rest of your answer gets a +1 though!